# How to move one image randomly when you click on the other image using html & javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I am a beginner with javascript. I have two images. One is for clicking, and the other one is for moving 10px to the left & right randomly. Once I click on the "high5" image, "pic2" image has to move randomly in any direction no more than 10 pixels. Every click is added to the score to generate total score at the end. I am stuck at this point, and I don't know where to go. Can someone help me, please?
As you can see, I have edited my code. I'm still having problems in:

1. Creating scoreboard to keep track of how many clicks the user
   clicked within 30 seconds.
2. I need a timer that counts 30 seconds.
3. Every time the picture in the middle moves, it keep going to the
   left.

HTML code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<!-- game.html
      Uses game.js
      Illustrates visibility control of elements
     -->
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Visibility control</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="score">
        0
    </div>

    <div id="high5" style="position: relative; left: 10px;">
        <img onclick= "moveImg(); clicked();" src="pics/high5.jpg" 
        style="height:250px; width:250px; " alt="Minion High Five" />
    </div>

    <div id="pic2" style="position: relative; top: 20px; left: 650px;">
        <img src="pics/pic2.gif" style="height:250px; width:350px;"/>
    </div> 

      <script type="text/javascript" src="game.js" ></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

javascript:

```
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var timer = 30;
var count = 0;
var isDone = true;

function moveImg() {
    x += Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) - 10;
    y += Math.floor(Math.random() * 20) - 10;

    pic2.style.left = x + "px";
    pic2.style.top = y + "px";

    if(timer > 0) {
        setTimeout("moveImg()", 50);
        timer--;
    }
    else {
        timer = 30;
    }
}

function clicked() {
    timer = 30;
    count++;
    score.innerHTML = count;
}
```

Comment: You missed right brackets `)` in each of your `if` statements. You also missed the closing braces `}` in the body of your `if` statements.

Comment: Thank you, but my codes still do not work. :( Any suggestion?

Comment: I started to help you out on this one but if I can be honest, there are severe things wrong with this code. You should separate everything out so it is readable, change pixelLeft to marginLeft, clean up your if and else endings, some have } and some do not (which goes back to, just space out your code, javascript should be read nicely beautified). parseInt to get the value of marginLeft, set the margin

Comment: Add function caller brackets in your HTML `onclick="moveImg()"`.

Comment: Also what you want? when clicked  more than one time.

Comment: I've updated my post, and I need three issues that need to be solved.

Comment: Learning takes time. Rather than start a big project like this where you end up with many things that dont work start a project and tackle one item like the timer for example. Then when you get that working start another small project that  moves the item when you click. That way if you have a problem its easier to ask a shorter question why one thing doesnt work and more people will offer an answer. You can then put everything together if you like Later on when you have a similar problem and you want to refer back to your past work, you have small steps for 1 issue that is easy to understand

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this: DO not use `onclick` inside HTML.I have added some jquery part,if you don't need change it accordingly or let me know.

```js
var high5,myVar;
$(function(){
$("img").on("click",function(){
 console.log($(this));
 if($(this).data('id') == "minion"){
 high5=document.getElementById('pic2');
 high5.style.left="10px";
 moveImg(); 
 }
});
  setInterval(function(){ myStopFunction(); }, 3000);//call to stop shacking after 3000 miliseconds.
});

function moveImg() {
 //alert("hi");
    var x;
    x = Math.floor(Math.random()*4)+1;
    left = parseInt(high5.style.left.replace('px', ''));
    console.log(x+ "," +left);
    if (x==4 && left >= 10) {
        high5.style.left = (left - 10) + 'px';;
        }
    if (x==3 && left <= 650) {
        high5.style.left = (left + 10) + 'px';
    }
    if (x==2 && left >= 10) {
        high5.style.left = (left - 10) + 'px';;
    }
    if (x==1 && left <= 450) {
        high5.style.left = (left + 10) + 'px';
    }
    
   myVar =  setTimeout(function(){moveImg();},100);
}
function myStopFunction() {
clearTimeout(myVar);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <div id = "high5"  style = "position: absolute;">
    <img src="pics/high5.jpg" style="height:250px; width:250px; 
       margin-top: 50px; margin-left: 50px; border:none;" 
 alt="Minion High Five" data-id="minion"/>
  </div>

  <div id = "pic2" style=" position: absolute; width:350px;height:250px;margin-left: 550px;border:1px solid black;margin-top:150px;">
    <img src="pics/pic2.gif" style="width:350px;height:250px;" alt="Minion High Five"/>
  </div>
```

Comment: Thank you for the code, but when I click the high5 image, pic2 has to shake.

Comment: Thank you so much. How can I make it stop shaking after few milliseconds?

Comment: Try the updated answer.You should mention every detail while asking the question ,it will help people to answer properly.If this answer helps then you can mark it as answer.